# Pagination php multiple query while

Tags: php, sql

Hello my problem is the following:
I have divided according to the results page ..
The problem is afiserea results
I have the following code:

```
<?php
  include('ttt_files/paginare.php');  
  $rezultate_pe_pagina = '2';
  $statement = "`anunt_standard` where `activat` = 0  AND prs_prv='$filtru_p' ";
  /* Inceputul stabiliri functiei numaratorelor */
  $page = (int) (!isset($_GET["page"]) ? 1 : $_GET["page"]);
  $limit = $rezultate_pe_pagina;
  $startpoint = ($page * $limit) - $limit;
  //Query pentru afisere si paginare
  /* Sfarsitul stabiliri functiei numaratorelor */
  $url = "{$server_url}anunturi/f/{$_GET['f']}/page/";
  echo "<div id='asezare_butoane'>".pagination($statement,$limit,$page,$url)."</div>";


  //afiseaza inregistrarile platite
  $query_pay = mysql_query("
                 SELECT * FROM {$statement} AND activat_plata = '1' 
                 AND sters = '0' ORDER BY data_adaugare DESC  LIMIT {$startpoint} ,
                 {$limit}");

  echo "
  <table border='0' width='950px' 
    style='border-collapse:separate; border-spacing:0px  5px;'>";         
  $i = 0;     
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_pay)) {
        include('continut_platit.php');              
  }             
  echo "</table>";
  //afiseaza inregistrarile normale
  $query = mysql_query("
                 SELECT * FROM {$statement} AND sters = '0' 
                 AND activat_plata = '0' 
                 ORDER BY data_adaugare DESC 
                 LIMIT {$startpoint} , {$limit}");

   echo "
       <table border='0' width='950px' 
          style='border-collapse:separate; border-spacing:0px 5px;'>";   
                 $i = 0;
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            include('continut.php');

       }

       echo "</table>";

       //afiseaza inregistrarile sterse
       $query_del = mysql_query("
              SELECT * FROM {$statement} 
              AND sters = '1' 
              ORDER BY data_adaugare DESC 
              LIMIT {$startpoint} , {$limit}");

       echo "<table border='0' width='950px' style='border-collapse:separate; border-spacing:0px 5px;'>";

                 $i = 0;

                   while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_del)) {
                        include('continut_sters.php');

                        }

                 echo "</table>";
?>
```

The problem is that it does not display 2 results per page as it is set now displays results from each query by 2 ie Paste in total 6 results:
2 - $ query_pay
2 - $ query
2 - $ query_del
But call figure out how to make it display only by 2 for example is the first page if added 2 records 'pay' to display only on those 2 .. Or if you are only 2 records the query to display only those 2: (
Function for paging

```
    <?php
   function pagination($query, $per_page = 10,$page = 1, $url = '?'){  
           $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as `num` FROM {$query}";
           $row = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
           $total = $row['num'];
                $adjacents = "2";
           $page = ($page == 0 ? 1 : $page);
           $start = ($page - 1) * $per_page;                                       

           $prev = $page - 1;                                   
           $next = $page + 1;
                $lastpage = ceil($total/$per_page);
           $lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;

           $pagination = "";
           if($lastpage > 1)
           {  
                  $pagination .= "<ul class='pagination'>";
                                        //$pagination .= "<li class='details'>Pagina $page din $lastpage</li>";
                  if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2))
                  {  
                         for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
                         {
                                if ($counter == $page)
                                   $pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>$counter</a></li>";
                                else
                                   $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}$counter/'>$counter</a></li>";                       
                         }
                  }
                  elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2))
                  {
                         if($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2))        
                         {
                                for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)
                                {
                                   if ($counter == $page)
                                          $pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>$counter</a></li>";
                                   else
                                          $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}$counter/'>$counter</a></li>";                        
                                }
                                $pagination.= "<li class='dot'>...</li>";
                                $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}$lpm1/'>$lpm1</a></li>";
                                $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}$lastpage/'>$lastpage</a></li>";       
                         }
                         elseif($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents * 2))
                         {
                                $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}1/'>1</a></li>";
                                $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}2/'>2</a></li>";
                                $pagination.= "<li class='dot'>...</li>";
                                for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++)
                                {
                                   if ($counter == $page)
                                          $pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>$counter</a></li>";
                                   else
                                          $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}$counter/'>$counter</a></li>";                        
                                }
                                $pagination.= "<li class='dot'>..</li>";
                                $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}$lpm1/'>$lpm1</a></li>";
                                $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}$lastpage/'>$lastpage</a></li>";       
                         }
                         else
                         {
                                $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}1/'>1</a></li>";
                                $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}2/'>2</a></li>";
                                $pagination.= "<li class='dot'>..</li>";
                                for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
                                {
                                   if ($counter == $page)
                                          $pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>$counter</a></li>";
                                   else
                                          $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}$counter/'>$counter</a></li>";                        
                                }
                         }
                  }

                  if ($page < $counter - 1){

                 $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}$next/'>Urmatoarea</a></li>";
                                //$pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$lastpage'>Ultima</a></li>";
                  }else{
                         $pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>Urmatoarea</a></li>";
                                //$pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>Ultima</a></li>";
                        }
                  $pagination.= "</ul>\n";       
           }


                return $pagination;
        }
?>
```

I thought to count total results above and to create a condition that is nustiu posters but how to put condition.
Or to put the 3 above the query results and number then I gather and share their work at 3:01 so? But go to a function and not know how to think

---

```
mysql_query("SELECT u.* FROM (
                                (SELECT * FROM anunt_standard WHERE `activat_plata`='1' AND `sters`='0' AND `activat`='0' ORDER BY data_adaugare DESC)
                                UNION
                                (SELECT * FROM anunt_standard WHERE `activat_plata`='0' AND `sters`='0' AND `activat`='0' ORDER BY data_adaugare DESC)
                                UNION
                                (SELECT * FROM anunt_standard WHERE `sters`='1' AND `activat`='0' ORDER BY data_adaugare DESC)
                                ) As u  LIMIT {$startpoint} , {$limit}")or die(mysql_error());
```

Thanks for the idea but the problem is that they fail to display in the order you want ... I mean nothing I write:

```
ORDER BY data_adaugare DESC
```

Comment: What is/are nustiu posters?

Answer (score 0):

If you're familiar with UNION in SQL, you may want to try creating a single query with LIMIT x,y at the end of it. Check out http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp if you haven't used UNION before.

You'll want something like:

```
SELECT u.* FROM (
    (SELECT... 1st query)
    UNION 
    (SELECT... 2nd query)
    UNION
    (SELECT... 3rd query)
) AS u LIMIT {$startpoint} , {$limit}
```

In response to your second post, UNION operates on a set of rows and that can create unpredictable sorting. You'll want to put "ORDER BY" at the end of the UNION.

Another alternative is encasing each select in another select, which seems silly, but it makes sorting work. Be cautioned that UNION ALL allows duplicate results, so if any of the unioned queries return the same row, it will be repeated.

```
SELECT u.* FROM (
    SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM anunt_standard
                   WHERE `activat_plata`='1' AND `sters`='0' AND `activat`='0'
                   ORDER BY data_adaugare DESC) A
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM anunt_standard
                   WHERE `activat_plata`='0' AND `sters`='0' AND `activat`='0'
                   ORDER BY data_adaugare DESC) B
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM anunt_standard
                   WHERE `sters`='1' AND `activat`='0'
                   ORDER BY data_adaugare DESC) C
) As u LIMIT {$startpoint} , {$limit}
```

Comment: I have a single table 'anunt_standard'